# Upload tensorboard logs from cloud storage to vertex ai - tensorboard

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I created a pipeline with vertex ai and added the code for creating and storing my tensorboard logs in cloud storage. The next step in the instructions here https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/experiments/tensorboard-overview#getting_started is to use the tb-gcp-uploader command to upload the logs to the tensboard experiment page. But I'm getting this message "'tb-gcp-uploader' is not recognized as an internal or external command". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run the command tb-gcp-uploader by installing the following package:

```
pip install google-cloud-aiplatform[tensorboard]
```